# Get rid of "net" tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The [net](/questions/tagged/net) tag seems about as non-descriptive and useless as one might hope to find, unless there's a "thing" tag or a "computer" tag.  Can we nuke it?

Comment: The net tag was a misspelled .net (retagged yesterday).

Answer (score 7):

The [net](/questions/tagged/net) tag is currently empty and will disappear on its own.

Comment: 160 questions so far right now. Could you please merge it in .net and synonymise them?

Comment: @abatishchev My first instinct was to say that surely not all of the questions were about .NET. Then I looked at the list. :) While some were unrelated (and I retagged them), the majority was .NET-related, so now there's a synonym in place. Things to keep an eye out for are Net::SSH in Perl and a couple other libraries called "Net". They should probably have their own tags anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed firstly I thought too it will be network related or maybe some unix util but most of them were just misspelled and also tagged by C# or another .NET related  technology.